# Apache NiFi Wait select FlowFile by attribute

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, wait, notify

I am creating a flow for processing some data from **multiple sources** (same platform, different customer). Each FlowFile is generated by triggering the **HandleHttpRequest** processor. I can only process one file at a time for certain customer. This process is also asynchronous (I am looping while I don't receive the response from the API that the process was finished).

What I have right now is a **Wait/Notify** flow, so after one **FlowFile** gets processed, **Wait** will release another file to process. However, this will only work for one customer. What I want is to have a dynamic number of **Wait** processors or one **Wait** processor, that can release **FlowFiles** conditionally (by attribute).

**Example**:

I have customer A and B. Each has generated **FlowFiles** with attribute

```
customer: ${cust_name}
```

These **FlowFiles** has been stopped in **Wait** processor and waiting for the notification by the **Notify** processor. The order of these files is unknown (order of files for one customer is always sorted). This means, that the queue can look like this (A3 B3 A2 A1 B2 B1). What I want is to **Notify** the **Wait** processor to release next A element or B element by attribute.

Is something like this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to what I wanted to achieve !
So I have a **Wait** processor accepting files with an attribute **customer**, which has either value of **A** or **B**.

The files are then flowing in a loop in the **Wait** processor into wait relationship.
[image]

What happens is, that the order of these files entering **wait queue** is always the same. The **Wait** processor always look up for the **first entry** in the queue ant that's it.

To achieve the perpetual cycling of FlowFiles, you need to configure the wait queue with **FirstInFirstOutPrioritizer**.

However, this will **not guarantee** that Wait processor will release the **oldest FlowFile**, because the wait queue is always changing.

But there is a solution for this. There is a **Wait Penalty Duration** attribute, which will skip the first file in the queue if it did not match the signal, then second, third ... until the desired oldest file was found (or penalty will expire). You can find the whole conversation here https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/3540

[image]

It works with **Run schedule** set to 0 and wait queue at default settings.